# Atualização de dados em um modulo com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com angular e faço chamada a um webservice que me retorna um JSON e queria saber como faço para atualizar o esse Json de tempos em tempos com angular, alguém poderia me dar uma ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o serviço `$interval`.

Ele é equivalente a API `window.setInterval`, porém dedicada para uso do AngularJS (lembre-se que o Angular precisa atualizar a view quando o modelo é alterado).

O uso deste serviço é bastante simples:

```
interval = $interval(fn, 1000, 0, true);
```

Descrição dos parâmetros:

1. Comando a ser executado quando no intervalo;
2. Intervalo em ms dos disparos;
3. Quantidade de repetições. Utilize 0 para infinito (padrão);
4. Se o Angular deve chamar o serviço `$apply` quando o disparo for finalizado (padrão).

No primeiro parâmetro `fn`, você deve realizar a chamada ao Web Service, provavelmente usando o serviço `$http`.

Comment: Eu posso passar a função que faz isso nesse parametro fn?

Comment: Sim. Só tome cuidado que se ela precisar de algum parâmetro, você terá que criar um wrapper sem parâmetros, ou modificar a função para que ela não precise mais do parâmetro.