# Como fazer meu app Ionic ter o json externo atualizado de acordo com novos conteudos?

Tags: json, ionic

Pois bem eu tenho um site que utiliza a JSON API do Wordpress e criei o site feito a mao consumindo dados JSON do wordpress. Criei um app para o site utilizando o "whitelist" do IONIC para poder pegar dados JSON de URL externa. Porém quando crio uma postagem nova no site o app não carrega esta nova alteração, ficando apenas com o conteúdo de quando dei um build no app.

Alguem me socorre?

Comment: você está fazendo uma nova request?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44925/atualiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-dados-em-um-modulo-com-angularjs/44927#44927

Comment: existe uma função no ionic que cria um "refresh" para o conteudo, você já pesquisou sobre isso? qual a versão do IONIC você esta usando?

Comment: Estou utilizando o v1, provavelmente eu não soube como pesquisar este problema.

Comment: Consegui.Obrigado

Comment: @PedroFranco Já que conseguiu, porque não cria uma resposta para sua própria pergunta? Assim você ajudará outros que tiverem a mesma dúvida no futuro.